# UWP BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger not triggering with service uuid filter

Tags: uwp, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

An in-process background task with trigger is being registered:

```
var trigger = new BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherTrigger();
trigger.AdvertisementFilter.Advertisement.ServiceUuids.Add(GattServiceUuids.CyclingSpeedAndCadence);

... more background code left out for simplicity ...
```

Unfortunately this never gets triggered when I run the app in `Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts` option.

Whenever I run the app normally with an advertisements watcher, I do get this info (so the service ID I am filtering is correct):

```
Local name:  'mydevice1234'
Company:     ''
Service ids: '00001816-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb;0000180f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'
```

Unfortunately I cannot use the company ID in the filter since the company is empty on advertisements...

Any ideas why this is not triggering? The documentation only mentions the company filter, but I cannot use that.

**Update 2019-10-10:**

To clarify: I can perfectly communicate with the bluetooth device.

Let me try to explain what I want. Whenever the app detects that it's not running (using a background task) but sees the device has come on-line, then it should show a message: do you want to start the app? This way the user can be reminded to start the companion app.

The background advertisements watcher, based on service ids without a company, seems not to work (although it *should* be possible if I understand the Bluetooth standards / documentation correctly).

Comment: I tested with official code sample and it works well, please refer this  [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothAdvertisement) and create an out process background task.

Comment: Thanks. Did you check with the example code with *ManufacturerData* or with the service guid?

Comment: Sure, I used the default `ManufacturerData = 0x1234`.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT just checked this code again. The example is *not* working for me. If you *remove* the ManufacturerData from the examples, and instead add a service uuid filter (in my case SpeedAndCadence), it's not showing the data from the background thread example. Foreground watcher works fine.

Note that ManufacturerData = [] for my device, so I cannot use a manufacturer filter.

Answer (score 1):

Manufacturer data is not mandatory according the bluetooth specification.From my perspective it does not matter.

@geertvanhorrik, you mentioned Foreground watcher is working fine. I suspect the problem to be with *Do not launch, but debug my code when it starts option* . To confirm this , is it possible to use any bluetooth protocol packet analyzer like wireshark to validate BackgroundWatcher is receiving the data?

Atleast it would be possible to confirm that Backgroundwatcher is receiving the data.

Comment: I will try without the 'Do not launch' mode. Also tried checking the bluetooth traffic, but could not get it to show anything in Wireshark (while network stuff is working fine).

Comment: The thing is: it seems to work fine with the manufacturer filter, so it appears to be a missing feature / bug in windows?

Comment: If the wireshark shows bluetooth activity in foregroundwatcher but not in backgroundwatcher, then is should be possibly be issue with bluetooth radio not receiving data when running in background.

Comment: I can't get wireshark to show any bluetooth activity when using the "Bluetooth Network Connection". Also tried the bluetooth npcap but didn't seem to change anything. It's a bluetooth adapter on my surface laptop, do I need an explicit separate one to test this?

Comment: No explicit setup needed. execute Wireshark on your surface laptop, and configure it to capture packets from bluetooth adapter connected to your machine

Comment: I did exactly that, and didn't show up anything. Even tried connnecting my phone, just to check if any bluetooth traffic could be captured.

Comment: I think i cannot help on wireshark, since i do not have microsoft surface to validate it.

Comment: Tried with another (generic) bluetooth adapter, no success either. Maybe you need specific hardware to intercept bluetooth traffic via wireshark?

Comment: As far as I could remember i was using on Windows 8 two years back. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/bluetooth-le-explorer/9n0ztkf1qd98?activetab=pivot:overviewtab is the only thing I can check out from Windows store.

Comment: It shows the device (just as my app can). Let me try to explain what I want. Whenever the app detects that it's not running (background thread) but sees the device comes on-line, then it should show a message: do you want to start the app?

So I can actively connect with the bluetooth, that's all working fine. But the background advertisements watcher *based on service ids without a company* is not working.

Comment: Does the Microsoft team have any updates on it?I am out of options here for the issue you face